# Вызов функции JavaScript для значения поля /p html

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть надпись на html:

```
<p class = "Test" id="Test" align="left" > Вот сюда вставить результат функции JavaScript </p>
```

В нее хочу вставить значение из функции JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function GetVasya(){
        return "Вася";
    }
</script>
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если функция возвращает HTML:

```js
function GetVasya() {
  return 'Вася';
}

document.querySelector('.Test').innerHTML = GetVasya();
```

```html
<p class="Test" id="Test" align="left"> Вот сюда вставить результат функции JavaScript </p>
```

Если функция возвращает простой текст:

```js
function GetVasya() {
  return 'Вася';
}

document.querySelector('.Test').textContent= GetVasya();
```

```html
<p class="Test" id="Test" align="left"> Вот сюда вставить результат функции JavaScript </p>
```

Comment: ``textContent``

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда в случае, если функция возвращает какой-то html, то в селектор он будет "подставляться" текстом, а не, собственно, тегами

Comment: Функции редко возвращают html. Нечего плодить уязвимости.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, заработало)